# Html.fromHtml(string ) is not parsing P tag in android

Tags: android, html

I need to get the body from the following file. When I use `Html.fromHtml(string)`, then I am getting the `body + some unformatted data` as

```
P {
    MARGIN-TOP: 0px;
    MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px 
}
```

`<P/>` tag will not work with `Html.fromHtml(string )`. Why?

Comment: Where did the raw data come from? Can you check it and paste it here

Comment: I don't think that fromHtml can handle css rules...

Comment: This is the text i have as string format ..now from this i need to get the body.


<html><head/><body><html dir="ltr">
 <head>
 <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
 <meta name="GENERATOR" content="MSHTML 8.00.7600.16385">
 <style id="owaParaStyle">P {
 MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px
 }
 </style>
 </head>
<body fPStyle="1" ocsi="0">
<div style="direction: ltr;font-family: Tahoma;color: #000000;font-size: 10pt;">Hai</div>
 </body>
 </html>

Answer (score 4):

Just Convert two times
given example hope so help u

```
String des=Html.fromHtml(item.getVoucher_Description()).toString();
txtdes.setText(Html.fromHtml(des));
```

Answer (score 2):

Here commonsware says that P tag is supported. [Supported TAGS by HTML.fromHtml() - Blog](http://commonsware.com/blog/Android/2010/05/26/html-tags-supported-by-textview.html)

For example you should use it in a string like this

```
<string name="htmlFormattedText">
          <![CDATA[
          <p>Text with markup for <strong>bold</strong>
          and <em>italic</em> text.</p>
          <p>There is also support for a
          <tt>teletype-style</tt> font.
          But no use for the <code>code</code>
          tag!</p>
          ]]></string>
```

Source From [Here](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-quick-tip-formatting-text-with-html-fromhtml/)

Comment: but in my html file P tag is like follows.

<style id="owaParaStyle">P {
 MARGIN-TOP: 0px; MARGIN-BOTTOM: 0px
 }
P is not as a tag.is this creating problem?

Comment: The list already says that , which tags are supported.. and that's it.. nothing more supported in that class.

Comment: If you still want to show some CSS and Styles then I think you will have to use `webview` instead of the edittext or textbox.

Comment: ok..thank u.but in my application i will get the body as html as above ,and i have menu options like "reply","replyall",when user clicks on reply/replyall i need to launch the mail client by putting body..but if i put body that p tag is creating problem.is there any alternative way to get the body from html page and pass to mail client?